# How do you print different things depending the user input?

Tags: c, scanf

First, I apologize if the question doesn't make sense as my English isn't that good...

My question is, how do we print out different things depending on the user input?
What I'm trying to do is: when user inputs integer, the program prints out the inputted number. When the user inputs something that's not integer (like symbols and characters), the program prints out "not integer".

my current idea (pseudo-code) is as follows:

```
`int main(){
    int value;
    printf("Enter numbers");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    if(value is integer){
        printf("%d", value);
    } else {
        printf("not integer");
    } 
    return 0;
}`
```

what gets me is the scanf; by using %d, I'm assuming that the user will input an integer values, but the user can input values that are not integers so I can't make a comparison using the if statement `if( value is integer)`. How can I make a comparison that will determine whether the inputted value is integer or not?

Comment: _by using %d, I'm assuming that the user will input an integer values, but the user can input values that are not integers_ it won't scan properly for e.g `scanf("%d",&value)` and given `11.5` a float value `scanf()` will not scan properly here itself, later how will you check as it was truncated .

Comment: Exactly, isn't doing scanf("%d") basically assuming that users will input decimal values (base 10) ? My primary concern as of now is to know how to print different stuffs depending on user inputs, let it be integer, or other things like character/symbols/etc.

Comment: one possible  way is that scan the input as  _string_ and then do operation on strings & check whether it contain any `dot(.)` or not. can use `atoi()` or `atof()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  So, if the user entered 'aboce' the returned value would be 0 (and the 'aboce' would still be in the I/O stream `stdin`)  You can easily use the check of the returned value to determine to make the determination of 'did the user enter a integer or not

Comment: You can't use `scanf` for your purpose, use `argv[]` argument pass or as `string operation by fgets() & atoi or atof`, Give a try if you stuck update query, some one will help you.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm not sure if checking returned value meant this: `if(scanf("%d",&value)==1)`  but this worked, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good thing or not.

You can use ASCII to check if the input type is an integer or not
(between 48 - 57 in ASCII)

it will be like this

```
char value;
int flag = 0; //to check true or false (0 means false, and 1 means true)
printf("Enter numbers");
scanf("%c", &value);
for(int i = 48; i <= 57; i++){
    if(value == i){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag == 1){
    printf("%c", value);
} else {
    printf("not integer");
}
```

Comment: This too seems to be do what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do you print different things depending the user input?

Step 1: Read the *line* of user input

```
char buf[100];
if (fget(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // something was entered
```

Step 2: test the string

```
  char *end;
  long value = strtol(buf, *end);
  // If the end is the same as the beginning, no conversion occurred.
  if (end == buf) {
    puts("not integer");
  }
    printf("%ld\n", value);
  }
}
```

Additional code could look for input that occurred after the integer.  Also code could test for a large number that overflowed the `long` range.

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows. It caters for different situations like inputting negative numbers and decimal numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char input[20];
    int wrongFlag = 0;
    scanf("%s", input);
    if (input[0] == '0' && strlen(input) > 1) {
        wrongFlag = 1;
        //for number starts with 0, and string length>1 eg: 010
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (i == 0 && (input[i] == '-' && strlen(input) > 2 && input[i + 1] == '0')) {
            //check first round only: negative number with length >2 and starts with 0 eg: -010.
            wrongFlag = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (i != 0 && !isdigit(input[i])) {
            //check following rounds, check if it is not digit
            wrongFlag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (wrongFlag) {
        printf("Not integer");
    }
    else {
        printf("integer");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char value[50];
    int len;
    printf("Enter maximum 50 digits\n");
    /* enter the values you wanted*/
    printf("Enter the value: ");
    gets(value);
    len = strlen(value);
    /*it will iterate upto the end of the user input*/
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(48<value[i] && value[i]<=57)
        {
            if(i==(len-1))
                printf("It's an integer");          
        }
        else{

            printf(" Not an integer");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```